# Refresh multiple div's

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I'm using the following code to get data refreshed every 2 seconds in 2 different div's

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function refreshTable(divId, typeId, serverDesc){

        $.get('getServerData.php?vTypeId=' + $(typeId).val() + '&vServerDesc=' + $(serverDesc).val(), function(data){
           $(divId).html(data);
           window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000)})
    }    


    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable("#Servers1", "#hdnTypeId1", "#hdnServerDesc1");
      refreshTable("#Servers2", "#hdnTypeId2", "#hdnServerDesc2");
    });    

</script>
```

I'm getting the correct data for the different div's but the refresh is not working. 
In the hdnTypeId fields and hdnServerDesc fields the correct data is passed through but the refresh is not working.

Comment: You need to call refreshTable with the required params (divId, typeId, serverDesc)

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to `refreshTable` when you call it in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval` if you want to do something every N seconds?

Comment: @Barmar setTimeout approach is better here i.e. call method only after getting some data via get. SetInterval can overlap with other get request if there is some delay in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function as the first parameter to window.setTimeout like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshTable(divId, typeId, serverDesc){

        $.get('getServerData.php?vTypeId=' + $(typeId).val() + '&vServerDesc=' + $(serverDesc).val(), function(data){
           $(divId).html(data);

           window.setTimeout(function() {
               refreshTable(divId, typeId, serverDesc);
           }, 2000)})
    }    

    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable("#Servers1", "#hdnTypeId1", "#hdnServerDesc1");
      refreshTable("#Servers2", "#hdnTypeId2", "#hdnServerDesc2");
    });    

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your are making a callback to refreshTable without parameters, change

```
window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000)
```

to

```
window.setTimeout(function(){refreshTable(divId,typeId,serverDesc);}, 2000)
```

Comment: ok, the refresh is working now, but the typeId and serverDesc has no values after the refresh. So the first time I see the values, but with the timeout I get undefined values. I'm pretty new at this stuff, so sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: are the values from the typeId and serverDesc elements being overwritten when you set the html of divId?

Comment: No, these are two hidden fields which are set in the div's which are dynamically build up:
        <div id="Servers<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnTypeId<?php echo $i; ?>" name="hdnTypeId<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $objResultType['TypeId'];  ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnServerDesc<?php echo $i; ?>" name="hdnServerDesc<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $objResultType['Desc'];  ?>" />
            <?php $i ++; ?>
        </div>

Comment: when I look in the source code the fields are still filled with the correct values:
 <div id="Servers1">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnTypeId1" name="hdnTypeId1" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnServerDesc1" name="hdnServerDesc1" value="Database Server" />
                    </div>

Comment: is that the original html or the html after you do the get and change the html?

Comment: this is the source code after a few refreshes and is the same as the sourcecode before the refreshes

Comment: ok now im running out of ideas, have you tried getting the values without jQuery and doing it like `document.getElementById("hdnTypeId1").value`?